# Python Create Executable From File

Tags: python, executable

I have a python project that I want to turn into an executable but I need to include a folder with multiple dependencies in it. How can I do that?

Also, how should I program in the directories (like with a bin folder)?

Comment: Check out py2exe which supports arguments to which you can supply dependencies.

Comment: So should I just have one dependency which is my bin folder and put everything in their including my .py file? Or should I have the .py file outside of the bin folder?

Comment: I'm telling you the documentation is at your disposal. Give it a good look.

Comment: if you still meet problems, it will be useful to include specific details of what are the error messages, so help can be more targeted! good luck!